# Polymer-Dart 1.0 inheritance of custom elements

Tags: dart, polymer, dart-polymer

after successfull setting up the 0.17-dev-interop-reverse Polymer-Dart library I'm finally able to write Polymer 1.0 apps in Dart. Yeyyyyyyy!!11
Thanks for helping me!

However, there was another question which came up. How to inherit from a custom element. E.g. I want to have a BasePage element which all actual elements inherit from.

Some code for you:

**base_page.html**

```
<dom-module id="base-page">
    <template>
        Yep, thats some content.
    </template>
</dom-module>
```

**base_page.dart**

```
@HtmlImport('base_page.html')
library test.page;

import 'dart:html';
import 'dart:js';
import 'package:polymer/polymer.dart';
import 'package:web_components/web_components.dart' show HtmlImport;

//@jsProxyReflectable
@PolymerRegister('base-page')
class BasePage extends PolymerElement {

  factory BasePage() => new Element.tag('base-page');

  BasePage.created() : super.created();

}
```

**test_page.html**

```
<dom-module id="test-page">
    <template>
        <shadow></shadow>
        Content of an actual page.
    </template>
</dom-module>
```

**test_page.dart**

```
@HtmlImport('test_page.html')
library test.app;

import 'dart:html';
import 'dart:js';
import 'package:polymer/polymer.dart';
import 'package:web_components/web_components.dart' show HtmlImport;
import 'package:test/base_page.dart';

//@jsProxyReflectable
@PolymerRegister('test-page')
class TestPage extends BasePage {

  factory TestPage() => new Element.tag('test-page');

  TestPage.created() : super.created();

}
```

I've done quite a lot with Polymer 0.5 before and inheritance has never been an issue, but for some reasons, I do not get the content of the `<base-page>` shown (`Yep, thats some content.` is missing).

I tried to move `<shadow>` outside of the `<template>` but it doesnt work. I also tried to add `extends='base-page'` as well as `extendsTag: 'base-page'` to the `<test-page>` but none of it seems to work.

Ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Polymer.js 1.0 only extending of native elements is supported, I'm pretty sure Polymer.dart 0.17 can't suppport this if it is not supported in Polymer.js 1.0.

This feature seems to be planned for a later Polymer.js version though.
Currently the closest is embedding instead of extending.

Answer (score 1):

The new polymer only supports extending native elements, https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/registering-elements.html#type-extension. In polymer dart this will actually work in some cases, but you would still have to duplicate the dom-module tag for each element which extends your base element.